# Microsoft Word VBA - IF & THEN Find word and print in another sheet

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a bit of novice when it comes to VBA (mostly navigate through the code by Recording actions and then altering it accordingly to what I need).

My current problem is the following:

I am going to compile hundreds of word Docs that contain **email addresses** from clients that I need. In order to make this as easy as possible, I would like to have some code that finds their emails AND additional information that surrounds the  email addresses (Name, Location,Job Title,and [possibly] Phone Number) and then copies and pastes the mentioned info to another designated document. The documents and the abovementioned info are formatted as such :

```
FirstName LastName
Location
Job title @ Company
email address - phone number
```

Now, I believe this will include and IF/THEN statement since not all clients have their email addresses in the documents.

*So, IF there is an email address THEN copy it along with the 3 lines above and the phone number that is separated by "a space" "-" "a space"AND paste it on another sheet. IF there is no email address, then keep going.*

This query code will probably include a FIND that needs to have a "@" and ".com" attached to the same string. This will be needed since the document also includes other text that has ".com" and "@" but not together.

This sounds harder than what it really is, but again I'm a novice so not completely sure. Feel free to ask any additional questions!

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely broad question, but I suggest you do the following:

- Use a [Scripting.FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx) to iterate through files in a folder, looking for Word documents
- Open the document using the Word Automation object model

  - [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838565.aspx) object
  - [Application.Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821628.aspx) property, and [Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840891.aspx) collection
  - [Documents.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845011.aspx) method, and the [Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822963.aspx) object, to create the destination document
  - [Documents.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182.aspx) method, to open existing documents
- Find emails within the document (via the [Document.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821853.aspx) property, and the [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882.aspx) object)

  - [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195912.aspx) property and the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839118.aspx) object
- If the [Find.Execute2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194658.aspx) method returns true, then:

  - Extend the range to the previous 3 paragraphs

    - [Range.MoveStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823249.aspx) method
  - Copy and paste the range to the destination document

    - You can write only the text to the destination document — [Range.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195101.aspx) property, and the Range.Insert-* methods
    - Or, you can use the clipboard [Range.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837718.aspx) and [Range.Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845105.aspx)
    - Or, you can export to an external file ([Range.ExportFragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822335.aspx)) and later import from the external file ([Range.ImportFragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839096.aspx))

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed response. I believe I'm a bit stuck though...this is what I have written so far and unfortunately am getting a "Run-time error '424' / Object required". ( [/] indicates paragraph break......Sub FindEmails() / Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content/ myRange.Find.Execute2007 FindText:="^064" & ".com" / If myRange.Find.Execute2007 = True Then
Selection.MoveStart Unit:=wdLine, Count:=-4/End If
myRange.Find.Execute2007.ExportFragment "LinkedInEmails", wdFormatDocument/End Sub.....If you could help me identify where I'm going wrong, that would be grreay. Thanks!

Comment: @GGp (1) When asking VBA questions with errors, it's important to include which line is causing the error -- it's the line with the yellow background. (2) IIRC, you need to store the results of `myRange.Find.Execute2007 ...` in a `Boolean` variable, because each time you repeat it the `Range` will be reduced to the found text if any. (3) When posting code in StackOverflow, if it's in blocks, then each line should start with four spaces; if inline, then the code should be delimited like `\`this\``.